# Strange issue in iOS in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

When I am making in app purchase in sandbox mode in my iOS project I am getting the error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (SSErrorDomain error 100.).

I have already restarted the app, made a clean build but that did not help.
What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Test only on a device, not the simulator, and make sure you have signed _out_ of the device's normal icloud account before trying this.

Comment: @matt I am testing it on my phone

Comment: Show your code, then. Maybe you're doing something wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have signed in with a sandbox account and not your actual Apple ID. You'll need to fully log out from the app store on your device to test.

Comment: Next double check your iTunesConnect in app purchase setup and that you are using a sandbox user from that account. sand box users can't come from different iTunesConnect accounts.

Comment: Are you trying to install betas thru test flight or from Xcode?